# how to create a user on a website database using vba

Tags: c#, vba

I am currently creating some client based software.

The client software uses an FTP function to create the clients name and folders based on that clients name. Then, when creating reports, it will upload that report to the current clients folder-reports.

> i.e uploads/clients/[clientname]/reports.

But for now I have to log in to the website and create the user name based on the clients name in my software.

My question: Is there away in `VBA` or `C#` to do this? Create a user name based on the current users name `<Field>`?

Comment: What APIs (if any) does "the website" offer to interact with its users' database?

Comment: Hi Francis, Thnx for your reply...apart from the usual website interface, in this case "Wordpress" there is nothing else on the domain. This runs on a Linux machine so to interface with the DB I use Php through the cpanel.

Comment: You could use WordPress's API http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will take a further look into this...how ever I'm not so accustomed in word press yet, so i am unsure how i will pass the functions/Variables over to WordPress for them to be inserted....Do you have any experience with this type of method? so you can give an example of how to code this or transfer the variables?

Comment: Start by looking around yourself, using some Googlefu skills. Try to come up with some basic idea, even pseudo-code if needs be at then ask a new question with more a precise problem if you do encounter one. Also, if you need to create FTP users through CPanel, it does have an API as well. How compatible it is with .NET, I do not know though. http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiFtp#Ftp::addftp

Comment: googling "wordpress api create user" yield lots of results, i'd start from there

Answer (score 0):

You could use WordPress's [`API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

Start by looking around yourself, using some Googlefu skills. Try to come up with some basic idea, even pseudo-code if needs be at then ask a new question with more a precise problem if you do encounter one.

Also, if you need to create FTP users through CPanel, [it does have an `API`](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiFtp#Ftp%3a%3aaddftp) as well. How compatible it is with .NET, I do not know though.

But you have enough reading ahead to try something for yourself for the moment.